# Get the length of messages storage Django

Tags: django

I am using messages framework of django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/)

When a user register, i do some check and add messages error to my storage :

```
 messages.error(request, gettext("username_already_exists"))
```

In my code i would like to know the length of messages.error, like that i can check if there is error or not in my form.

I tried this :

```
    if len(messages.error) <= 0:
      User.objects.create_user(
          username,
          email,
          password,
      )
```

But i can't because message 'object of type 'module' has no len()'

Do you know a way to check if there is messages errors stored in the messages Framework please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Don't try to check the length, just check `if messages.error` and don't use len()

Comment: hello ! Thank for your help, but this will not work i tried it. messages.error always exists, even if there is no error. so the condition will be true everytime.

Comment: try `if messages`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok my bad i didn't look enough on document.
Here the answer :

you have to use get_messages from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

then you can do `if len(get_messages(request)) <= 0:`